# Is it possible to get a list of WinAPIs that call SendMessage or other locking APIs internally?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, winapi

I'm facing a task of locating what is causing our production app to sporadically lock up its main/GUI thread on an end-user's machine. Unfortunately the intermittent nature of this bug and the inability to install and run any debugging/tracking tools in that environment makes locating the cause way more difficult. The current approach is to try to place traces around possible locking APIs and see which one may be causing the lock-up.

In light of that I'm curious, if there's a list of WinAPIs that call [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or other locking WinAPI internally? (Which I believe may be a primary reason for deadlocks in the main thread.)

PS. I already checked the following kernel APIs that may be involved in the lock-up: WaitForSingleObject, WaitForMultipleObjects, etc. that were used in the app and all of them checked out.

Comment: IME, there are no hidden 'SendMessage' calls to any other thread in the other API calls or any GUI components I have ever seen. Recursive SendMessage() calls to the GUI thread are common, however, in visual component methods/member functions.  Surely, you don't have calls to WFSO, WFMO from the main thread, do you?

Comment: SendMessage() isn't 'locking'. It's essentially just a procedure call that calls your window procedure. Any locking is in your own code.

Comment: When you get a dead lock, get the client to create a dump file. Then you can load that dump file in VS and debug it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks. Is there any way to create a dump automatically from my C++ code?

Comment: If the program has deadlocked then your code is no good. Create a dump from, for instance Process Explorer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, only the main thread is deadlocked. I can still communicate with the worker threads in that process.

Comment: Create the dump file the way I say.